cypress test problem with global variable and array / wrap null
I have a problem in a cypress the test run basing on JavaScript.
If I run the following test probably the arrays and / or global variable / array do not work.
In the browser test step log it says "wrap null". So I assume the values and arrays are empty. Is that so?
// Global variable for later use
let globalValues;

describe('Test a specific page', () => {
    it('Check a specific table', () => {

        let valuesArray = [];

    // Run through the table row and save values in an array

        cy.get('.table1 > tbody > tr.table_class3 > td:nth-child(1)').each(($e1, index, $list) => {
            var titletext = $e1.text()
            if (titletext.includes('Amount Summery')) {
                let values = [];
                // Run through the columns 2 to 15
                for (let i = 2; i <= 15; i++) {
                    cy.get(`.table1 > tbody > tr.table_class3 > td:nth-child(${i})`).eq(index).then(function (amount) {
                        values.push(amount.text().trim());
                    });
                }

                valuesArray.push(values);
            }
        });

    // Wait until all values are read and save them into the global variable

        cy.wrap(null).should(() => {
            globalValues = valuesArray;
        });

    // The global variable is ready to use for other tasks in the test

    })
})

Maybe this part is synchron?
cy.wrap(null).should(() => {
        globalValues = valuesArray;
    });

If I do something like this for asynchronous reasons:
cy.get('#anHTMLelement').then(function(wrapfunction){
    cy.wrap(null).should(() => {
            globalValues = valuesArray;
        });
})

This does not work neither.
I do not find the error. Any idea?

I think the core issue here is your synchronous for loop, wrapping around an async Cypress command. See if this SO solves your problem -> Cypress IO- Writing a For Loop

You can change your cy.wrap().should() line to assert the data is present
cy.wrap(globalValues).should('have.length.gt', 0)    // retries until true

but as @rubio says that only ensures the data is present inside command callbacks, not at the test context level, for example
HTML Table
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 3</td>
      <td>Cell 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

Test failing at test context usage of globalValues
let globalValues = [];

it('getting table data with Cypress commands', () => {
  
  cy.get('table tbody tr td')
    .each(td => {
      globalValues.push(td.text())
    })

  cy.wrap(globalValues).should('have.length.gt', 0)

  // passes
  cy.wrap(globalValues).should('deep.eq', ['Cell 1', 'Cell 2', 'Cell 3', 'Cell 4'])

  // fails 
  const thirdCell = globalValues[2]  
  cy.wrap(thirdCell).should('eq', 'Cell 3')
})



Using jQuery to extract data in the test context
If the page is fully loaded, you can use jQuery equivalent to Cypress commands:
it('getting table data with jQuery commands', () => {
  
  Cypress.$('table tbody tr td')
    .each((index, td) => {
      globalValues.push(td.innerText)
    })

  cy.wrap(globalValues).should('have.length.gt', 0)

  // passes
  cy.wrap(globalValues).should('deep.eq', ['Cell 1', 'Cell 2', 'Cell 3', 'Cell 4'])

  // passes 
  const thirdCell = globalValues[2]  
  cy.wrap(thirdCell).should('eq', 'Cell 3')
})



Change wrap() to then(), but you may have to use the value inside the then() depending on what your "other tasks" are.
// Run through the table row and save values in an array
cy.get(...)
  .each(...)
  .then(() => {
    globalValues = valuesArray;

    // can use result here (obvious)
  });

// can only use globalValues at this point inside other .then() or .should()
// for example 
cy.get('some-selector').invoke('text').should('eq', globalValues[0][2])

Other option to avoid putting all other tasks in .then(), gather the data in before() or beforeEach().
let globalValues 

before(() => {
  // Run through the table row and save values in an array
  ...

  cy.then(() => globalValues = valuesArray)
})

it('uses globalValues in the test', () => {
  // globalValues is set properly
})

This works because Mocha before() and it() blocks complete all commands before running the next block.
You can find out general concepts about global values from this page Variables and Aliases
